# Why am I getting type mismatch from label in access form?

Tags: ms-access

I am getting values from labels that are formatted as Percent (0.00%).

Therefore, I cast it to a double `CDBL(label.caption)` and I get the type-mismatch error.... see my code:

```
Forms(frmName).Label80.Caption = format(CDbl(Forms(frmName).Label123.Caption) + CDbl(Forms(frmName).Label162.Caption), "Percent")
```

Originally:
`label123` has **10.00%** value and `label162` has **0.00%** value

so if I do `cdbl(label123)` it gives me 10 (good!)

if I do `cdbl(label162)` it produces an error

if I do `val(label162)` it produces an error

I'm thinking it has something to do with 0?? I can't seem to figure this out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the % signs:

```
Forms(frmName).Label80.Caption = Format(Val(Replace(Forms(frmName).Label123.Caption, "%", "")) + Val(Replace(Forms(frmName).Label162.Caption, "%", "")), "Percent")
```

**Edit:**

Using *Val*, only works having *dot* (.) as the decimal separator.

For a *universal solution*, use *CDbl* or *CCur* as these convert the localised format correctly where a value formatted as percent may display as `10,48%`.

```
Forms(frmName).Label80.Caption = Format(CDbl(Replace(Forms(frmName).Label123.Caption, "%", "")) + CDbl(Replace(Forms(frmName).Label162.Caption, "%", "")), "Percent")
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this but I ended up using the replace function and it worked. As for the other two method mentioned, I did not try it but I am sure that that method would work also. thank you for your help!

Comment: See my comment to Lee's answer, please.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [`Format`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530) function to parse the percentage and return a string containing the equivalent value in **General Number** format, so that it may be successfully converted using the [`CDbl`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-conversion-functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) function, e.g.:

```vb
Forms(frmName).Label80.Caption = Format(CDbl(Format(Forms(frmName).Label123.Caption, "General Number")) + CDbl(Format(Forms(frmName).Label162.Caption, "General Number")), "Percent")
```

The advantage of this method is that the [`Format`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530) function recognises that the string represents a percentage and therefore automatically handles the division by 100:

```vb
?Format("10.48%", "General Number")
0.1048
```

The use of [`CDbl`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-conversion-functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) also allows for regional differences in decimal number representation (e.g. the use of a comma in place of a period) - my thanks to @Gustav for pointing this out.

Comment: This is the generic and universal method, as Format correctly recognises a localised format where, say, the decimal separator is comma. However, Val cannot be used to convert to a numeric values, as it only accepts dot as the decimal separator. Thus (having comma as the separator): `NumericValue = CDbl(Format("10,48%", "General Number"))`.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for raising this point, I have updated my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following template for each label.  The evaluate takes care of the percent sign.

```
L0 = CDbl(Evaluate(Label0.Caption))
```

Comment: But Evaluate is: 1) Terribly _slow_, about 1 full second. 2) accepts _only dot_ as the decimal separator, thus will fail if the decimal separator is anything else.